# Callback not firing on edit control

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to attach a callback event handler to a windows control. My code is below:

**URLInput.c**

```
#include <windows.h>

#define ID_EDITCHILD 100

LRESULT CALLBACK URLInputWndProc(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) // Breakpoint set here never fires
    {
        ...
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

HWND URLInput(HWND hwnd)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.lpszClassName = L"Edit Control";
    wc.lpfnWndProc  = URLInputWndProc;
    wc.hInstance    = hInstance;

    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        L"EDIT",
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
        0,
        0,
        100,
        100,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU) ID_EDITCHILD,
        (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
        NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    return hwnd;
}
```

In **main.c** I call like so:

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(  
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nShowCmd)
{
...
URLInputHwnd = URLInput(hwnd);
...
```

It renders fine. But, if I set a breakpoint on line 11 `switch(uMsg)` it never breaks. I'm expecting it to break when the window is created for example. Or, when entering text into the input. But this doesn't happen.

I've checked the MSDN documentation, although I can't find anything on using `WNDCLASS` with controls.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: it's been ages, but shouldn't the class name in `CreateWindowExW ` (`L"EDIT"`) match the class name you registered the callback for (`L"Edit Control"`) ?

Comment: I thought that too. I tried both with `L"EDIT"`. Doesn't render at all if I do that.

Comment: the example here: [Creating a Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/creating-a-window) uses the same name.

Comment: Ah yes, but that's for the main window. I read somewhere in the docs when creating a window for a control you have to specify the control class. Like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/use-a-multiline-edit-control

Comment: I think you need to do something like [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview) to do that.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas for help in the comments. I solved my problem subclassing the created component.

**URLInput.c**

```
#include <windows.h>

#define ID_EDITCHILD 100

static WNDPROC oldURLInputProc = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK URLInputWndProc(
    HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        /* Do something with messages */
    }

    return CallWindowProc(oldURLInputProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND URLInput(HWND hwnd)
{
    return CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        L"EDIT",
        NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
        0,
        0,
        100,
        100,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU) ID_EDITCHILD,
        (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
        NULL
    );
}

void setOldURLInputProc(WNDPROC wndProc)
{
    oldURLInputProc = wndProc;
}
```

And in **main.c**:

```
URLInputHwnd = URLInput(hwnd);
/* Error checking */
setOldURLInputProc((WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr (URLInputHwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)URLInputWndProc));
```

The Microsoft documentation helped: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview

Everything works fine.